PINN is not learning
I am trying to get started with pinns so i build this simple script to train an mlp using only the ode. The ode i am trying to solve is y = dy/dx. I am using numpy in this script and no other ml frameworks. Things I tried but didn't work:

Tried relu and tanh
Tried learning rate from 0.1 to 1e-6
Tried Xavier and He weight initialisation and other methods
Tried both numerical and analytical differentiation to find dydx

'''
import numpy as np
from math import sqrt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def tanh(x):
    return np.tanh(x)

def tanh_derivative(x):
    return 1 - np.tanh(x)**2

def relu(x):
    return np.maximum(0, x)

def relu_derivative(x):
    return np.where(x > 0, 1, 0)

activation_function = relu
activation_function_derivative = relu_derivative

def initialize_adam(parameters):
    v = {}
    s = {}
    
    for key in parameters.keys():
        v[key] = np.zeros_like(parameters[key])
        s[key] = np.zeros_like(parameters[key])
        
    return v, s

def initialize(n1, n2, n3, n4):
    
    W1 = np.random.uniform(-1/sqrt(n1),1/sqrt(n1),size = (n2, n1))
    B1 = np.random.uniform(-0.5, 0.5, size=(n2, 1))
    W2 = np.random.normal(-1/sqrt(n2),1/sqrt(n2),size = (n3, n2))
    B2 = np.random.uniform(-0.5, 0.5, size=(n3, 1))
    W3 = np.random.normal(-1/sqrt(n3),1/sqrt(n3),size = (n4, n3))
    B3 = np.random.uniform(-0.5, 0.5, size=(n4, 1))

    parameters = {'W1':W1,'W2':W2,'W3':W3,'B1':B1,'B2':B2,'B3':B3}
    return parameters


def forward_propagation(A0, parameters:dict):
    W1 = parameters['W1']
    W2 = parameters['W2']
    W3 = parameters['W3']
    B1 = parameters['B1']
    B2 = parameters['B2']
    B3 = parameters['B3']

    Z1 = np.dot(W1, A0) + B1
    A1 = activation_function(Z1)
    Z2 = np.dot(W2, A1) + B2
    A2 = activation_function(Z2)
    Z3 = np.dot(W3, A2) + B3
    Y_hat = Z3 #Y_hat

    forward = {'Z1':Z1,'A1':A1,'Z2':Z2,'A2':A2,'Z3':Z3,'Y_hat':Y_hat}
    return forward

def back_propagation(A0,Y,forward:dict,parameters:dict,dydx):
    W1 = parameters['W1']
    W2 = parameters['W2']
    W3 = parameters['W3']

    A1 = forward['A1']
    A2 = forward['A2']
    Y_hat = forward['Y_hat']

    Z1 = forward['Z1'] 
    Z2 = forward['Z2']
    Z3 = forward['Z3']


    network_initial_condtion = forward_propagation(A0[0][0]*np.ones_like(A0), parameters) #netowrk ouput at x = A0[0][0]
    Y0 = network_initial_condtion['Y_hat']

    
    initial_condition_error = Y[0] - Y0
    ode_error = dydx - Y_hat
    

    l1 = 1 #weight of ode error
    l2 = 1 #weight of intitial condition error
    
    m = A0.shape[1]

    dldy = (1/m) * (l1*ode_error + l2*initial_condition_error)

    dldz3 = dldy
    dldw3 = np.dot(dldz3, np.transpose(A2))
    dldb3 = np.sum(dldz3,axis=1, keepdims=True)

    dlda2 = np.dot(W3.T, dldz3)
    dldz2 = dlda2 * activation_function_derivative(Z2)
    dldw2 = np.dot(dldz2, np.transpose(A1))
    dldb2 = np.sum(dldz2,axis=1, keepdims=True)

    dlda1 = np.dot(W2.T, dldz2)
    dldz1 = dlda1 * activation_function_derivative(Z1)
    dldw1 = np.dot(dldz1, np.transpose(A0))
    dldb1 = np.sum(dldz1,axis=1, keepdims=True)


    backward = {'W1':dldw1,'B1':dldb1,'W2':dldw2,'B2':dldb2,'W3':dldw3,'B3':dldb3}

    return backward


def gradient(forward:dict,parameters:dict):
    W1 = parameters['W1']
    W2 = parameters['W2']
    W3 = parameters['W3']

    Y_hat = forward['Y_hat']
    Z1 = forward['Z1'] 
    Z2 = forward['Z2']

    # graidents in relation to network outpout Y_hat
    dydy = np.ones_like(Y_hat )
    dydz3 = dydy

    dyda2 = np.dot(W3.T, dydz3)
    dydz2 = dyda2 * activation_function_derivative(Z2)


    dyda1 = np.dot(W2.T, dydz2)
    dydz1 = dyda1 * activation_function_derivative(Z1)

    dydx = np.dot(W1.T, dydz1)

    return dydx


def update_adam(parameters, grads, v, s, t, learning_rate=None, beta1=0.9, beta2=0.999, epsilon=1e-8):
    v_corrected = {}
    s_corrected = {}
    
    for key in parameters.keys():
        v[key] = beta1 * v[key] + (1 - beta1) * grads[key]
        s[key] = beta2 * s[key] + (1 - beta2) * (grads[key] ** 2)

        v_corrected[key] = v[key] / (1 - beta1 ** t)
        s_corrected[key] = s[key] / (1 - beta2 ** t)

        parameters[key] -= learning_rate * (v_corrected[key] / (np.sqrt(s_corrected[key]) + epsilon))

    return parameters, v, s

def mean_squared_error(Y_hat, Y):
    mse = np.mean((Y_hat - Y) ** 2)
    return mse


def train(A0, Y, epochs, a, n1, n2, n3, n4):

    parameters = initialize(n1, n2, n3, n4)
    v,s = initialize_adam(parameters)
    for i in range(1, epochs + 1):

        forward = forward_propagation(A0, parameters)
        dydx = gradient(forward,parameters)
        gradients = back_propagation(A0,Y,forward,parameters, dydx)
        parameters,v,s = update_adam(parameters, gradients, v, s, i, learning_rate=a)

        if i % 100 == 0 or i==1:
            Y_hat = forward['Y_hat'].flatten()
            mse = mean_squared_error(Y_hat, Y)
            print(f'Epoch: {i}/{epochs} MSE: {mse}')

    return Y_hat.flatten()

n1 = 1   #input
n2 = 18  #hidden 1
n3 = 18  #hidden 2
n4 = 1   #output

X = np.linspace(0, 3, 200)

Y = np.exp(X) #ode solution

m = len(X)
A0 = X.reshape((n1, m))

epochs = 1000
a = 1e-5  #learning rate


Y_hat = train(A0, Y, epochs, a, n1, n2, n3, n4)


plt.plot(X,Y,label ='ODE solution')
plt.plot(X,Y_hat,label='PINN solution')
plt.grid()
plt.legend()
plt.show()

